# Lag Android app after some time

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-asynctask, lag

Well the question is that I have an app with multiple activities. The main activity runs several animations and the problem is that if I run the app and stay in the main activity everything is all right but if I go to another activity (the setting activity, for example) and come back to the main one, after some time the hole app begins to lag.
Any clue about why is this happenning? May the other activities keep running in background or something like that?
Thank you all.

Comment: Can you post a simple example that will allow other users to reproduce the problem?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

As far as your scenario is concerned, try following

1. Set up proper navigation within your app.
2. If you keep closing and opening your activities (when your activity is still holding on resources), your memory usage keeps piling up. So make sure you release all resources like camera, or finish an animation before calling finish();
3. Try different android:launchMode options for your Main Activity /Home screen activity. (this depends on your app design)
4. In order to find who is calling your app to use more memory, try https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html

PS. You could've given more details like @Michiyo mentioned.